# Blending Mode Options Missing After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm trying to change my blending mode on After Effects CC 2015, but I have no options on certain layers. Only 2 of my layers have options to change the blending mode. How do I change it so all of my layers have that option?

Thanks,

Natasha[image]

Comment: That looks very strange. Lights and Cameras don't have blending modes, but precomps and normal layers (even nulls and guide layers) should. Have you tried restarting AE?

Comment: There are effects on that layer?

Comment: If they were precomps (like layer 6) and collapse transforms is on (the sun icon) you won't be able to set a blending mode. Shouldn't happen for layer 7  and 8 though.

Comment: My guess is that layers only have blending modes if they have alpha channels associated with them.  If your layer has no alpha channel, what would be the meaning of the blending mode?

Comment: Blending modes can be applied without needing alpha e.g. `lighten` is mathematically `A > B ? A : B` where A is value of the R/G/B plane in top layer, and B bottom layer. And in any case, I believe AE assigns a default alpha of fully opaque if the media doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0):

Check your 3D Renderer. Blending and Compositing may not work if your Renderer is Cinema4D or Ray-Traced. Stick with Classic

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the tutorial below?

I have found that we need to change the composition settings.

**If you want access to the blending modes, ensure your composition is using the Classic 3D rendered. This can be found by going to your composition settings, click on Advanced tab, then select it from the Renderer drop down list.**

Thanks to Declan Smith on https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/2/1028397